# Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found for TypeScript in Windows machine

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a TypeScript project. The project folder structure and tsconfig.json file is shown below:

[image]

And my launch.json file is shown below:

[image]

When I am doing the debug, I can see that .map file are being generated, and since I added:

```
"sourceMaps": true,
"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}\\typeScript\\**\\*.js"]
```

in my launch file. I do not know why VS Code is still giving me "Breakpoint ignored ..." when I set a breakpoint in one of the .ts files. It seems VS Code can not see the .map file or interpret it incorrectly somehow.

I am attaching the screenshot of the generated map file. The path looks right.

[image]

The only thing when I noticed when I played with these config file was that the windows file path in tsconfig.json only recognize "\\" instead of "/". I am seeing in .map file everything is "/". I am not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: you can debug it from the browser console by setting breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything for sure by looking at the information you have provided. But here's what I have been doing:

This is what my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2016",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules",
        "../*.js"
    ]
}
```

And this is what my directory structure looks like:

[image]

If you pay attention you would see my src folder and build folder(containing resultant transpiled JS and map files) lives side by side which really helps me maintain a logical directory structure.

Ok, now comes the launch config:

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Start and Debug",
            "preLaunchTask": "nb-tsc-watch",
            "timeout": 10000,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/src/app.ts",
            "restart": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/backend//build/**/*.js"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
```

You can use whatever preLaunchTask you want to use, or even skip it.

This is what I do in my task `nb-tsc-watch`

```
{
            "label": "nb-tsc-watch",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "backend/src/tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ]
        }
```